# Firestore .orderBy() to also return documents without the field being queried

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I updated a collection of documents with a new field that corresponds to a new feature. A rating out of 5. Previously I had a list all the documents in the order they were created in. Now I want to show all the documents in order of their rating. The problem with using .orderBy is that it only returns the newer documents with the rating field. Is there a way to return all documents, in order of rating, but to also include document that don't have ratings at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Firestore queries are optimized to return documents in a single range. Your requirement essentially become an `OR` condition, where it'd need to return documents from two ranges. This currently isn't possible in Firestore queries.

Comment: I think it's a valid request, so you might want to consider [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Query fallbackability feature filed.